# audio packet type

Tags: c, struct, udp, alsa

I am starting working on a project that transmits G.711 audio over Ethernet, written in C (not C++) and running on Fedora 15. Rather than doing the smart thing and using RTP, I am using UDP to transfer the audio data.
To somewhat overcome the problem of re-ordering of packets I have decided to use a struct in the body of each packet that looks a bit like this:

```
struct payload {
  char cc;
  char audio_data[160];
};
```

The variable "cc" is a continuity counter that runs from 0-15, and when the packet arrives at the recipient it is put into an array of these structs based upon the value of the cc. The audio output routine then loops through this array and plays the data.

My question is, is this the best way to package the audio? The output array will end up being two-dimensional and surely it will be slow reading through each member and writing that to the output? Is there a way to define a type that is 160 bytes wide that i can just write to the audio interface at the other end?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, as would links to helpful resources on ALSA (which seem to be very rare!)

Josh

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question/problem.  What is it you are trying to avoid/optimise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you worry about cache optimization? I hope you profiled this simpler approach before complicating it. If cache misses is a real problem I would suggest to use [ring (circular) buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). It will be your [jitter buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitter#Jitter_buffers) too. This gives you fixed memory footprint and consecutive memory for faster access.

Since G.711 is constant bitrate codec, you can choose buffer size in time units (200 ms for conversation).  You play always the last packet in the buffer. For example, the last packet you received has `cc` = `n`, then you receive `cc` = `m` (> `n`). So you mark all packets between `n` and `m` as missing and replace them if you receive them later.

Comment: I was hoping my looping array idea would work as a ring buffer!
The main concern I have is needing to cycle through the `char` array and write each byte one by one to the soundcard, when what I would prefer to do is write a 180-byte chunk so that the hardware can deal with it at its own rate. Can I define a type that is 180 bytes wide?

Comment: sure, `char[180]` if `sizeof(char) == 1` on your target platform

Comment: aha, so 

    `typedef char[180] audio_data_chunk;
    audio_data_chunk adata;
    snd_pcm_read(handle, adata, sizeof(adata);`

then

    `snd_pcm_writei(handle, adata, sizeof(adata);`

Thankyou very much!